# HTML 5 Peer to Peer Video Possibilities?

Tags: html, p2p, adobe-stratus

Is there anything in HTML 5 that might allow peer to peer video ala Adobe Stratus and Flash 10?

There's lots of cool possibilities with P2P video and it'd be nice to build such applications without having to rely on Flash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Ericcson Lab's blog on [HTML5 Peer to Peer Conversational Video](http://www.ericsson.com/research-blog/context-aware-communication/beyond-html5-peer-peer-conversational-video/).

They have a demo of a WebKit build that can establish peer to peer video chat connections using HTML5 and a browser.

Comment: hey is this webkit available somewhere? Couldn't find it on their site

Answer (score 3):

http://swarmplayer.p2p-next.org/ adds a P2P transport protocol to Firefox that allows <video src="p2p://" > functionality. P2P transport is BitTorrent compatible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), HTML has added `audio` and `video` elements, and is adding support for peer-to-peer connections.

Comment: This is an important part of it. Can it send the video data p2p?
http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#sending0 seems to suggest it's possible but inefficient.