# How can I make a direct person-to-person chat widget for my website that doesn't use server resources?

Tags: wordpress, widget, chat, live

I would like to add live text chat to my website, but without using too many server resources or a third party application. I'm not concerned about keeping a chat log/history at this point. How would I go about making a website chat widget (preferably WordPress friendly) that would only use server resources to establish the initial connection between 2 logged in users, but that would essentially let them chat live without relaying the message through my server? Is this technically feasible? Does a product like this exist already? I've searched could not find any one-time-fee live chat solutions that don't route through my server or through a third-party server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022383/how-to-make-a-browser-to-browser-peer-to-peer-connection), but that is from 2011/2012.

A quick googling seems to suggest [WebRTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) might be a good choice for this sort of thing.

A few more minutes of research yields [this](http://simplewebrtc.com/), a javascript library for working with WebRTC.

Even better: [here](https://github.com/bndr/webRTC-php) is an example of a php chat server using WebRTC. This is probably what you'll want, seeing as WordPress is PHP.

Hopefully this is enough info to get you started. Good luck!