# How could I share an HTML element between 2 or more computers?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

So I have a [stopwatch](https://gillamsclass.github.io/stopwatch.html) built and what I'm trying to do is "share" the same stopwatch between 2 or more computers while keeping functionality. What I mean by this is say I start then stop the stopwatch on my computer (pc1) and it lands on 0:01:43, a different computer (pc2) which the stopwatch is shared with stopped and started in real time and was also on 0:01:43, and if I start and stop it on pc2 then the time would be reflected on pc1. How can I code this kind of functionality with JavaScript and a WebRTC api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share an HTML element between multiple computers / browsers.

What you CAN do is share data either by having a back-end store the state OR by using p2p. See [How can I make a browser to browser (peer to peer) connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022383/how-can-i-make-a-browser-to-browser-peer-to-peer-connection)

One for sure part of your state would be the UTC timestamp when the stopwatch started.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will definitely check that out.

Comment: One word of warning is that with P2P you won't have a single-source of truth for your data and will have to find a way to keep the state for each peer in sync.